# Trying to make a connect go gmail imap through sockets in c++ but without success

Tags: c++, sockets, gmail, imap

i'm trying to connect to gmail through sockets in c++...i seem not to get gmail to reply with the * OK message

this is my code

`#include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Client.h"

    #include <WinSock2.h>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <iostream>


    #define SCK_VERSION1 0x0101   //version 1 of winsock
    #define SCK_VERSIOM2 0x0202   //version 2 of winsock

    using namespace std;


    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        long Successful;
        WSAData WinSockData;
        WORD DLLVERSION=MAKEWORD(2,1);   
        Successful=WSAStartup(DLLVERSION,&WinSockData);  

        char MESSAGE[1024]="",MESSAGE1[1024]="";
        SOCKADDR_IN ADDRESS;
        SOCKET Sock;
        Sock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);//socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);
        struct hostent *host;

        host=gethostbyname("smtp.gmail.com");


        ADDRESS.sin_addr.s

_addr=*((unsigned long *)host->h_addr_list[0]);//inet_addr(Ip);
    ADDRESS.sin_family=AF_INET;
    ADDRESS.sin_port=htons(993);


    cout<<"connecting..."<<endl;
    if(connect(Sock,(SOCKADDR*) &ADDRESS,sizeof(ADDRESS))!=0){
        cout<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;                   //if there was an error then print it out
    }
    else{
        cout<<"connected"<<endl;
        int DataEnd=0;
        do{
            long Successful=recv(Sock,MESSAGE1,sizeof(MESSAGE1)/sizeof(char),NULL);        //the listen if he got all
            strcat_s(MESSAGE,MESSAGE1);
            cout<<MESSAGE1;
            for(int i=0;i<1024;i++){
                if(MESSAGE[i]=='\0'){
                    DataEnd=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }while(DataEnd==0);

        cout<<MESSAGE<<endl;

        for(int i=0;i<=(int)strlen(MESSAGE);i++){
            MESSAGE[i]='\0';
        }

        Successful= send(Sock,"a1 login mail@gmail.com pass\r\n",(int)strlen("a1 login mail@gmail.com pass\r\n"),NULL);

        DataEnd=0;
        do{
        long Successful=recv(Sock,MESSAGE1,sizeof(MESSAGE1)/sizeof(char),NULL);        //the listen if he got all
        strcat_s(MESSAGE,MESSAGE1);
        for(int i=0;i<1024;i++){
            if(MESSAGE[i]=='\0'){
                DataEnd=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        }while(DataEnd==0);
        cout<<MESSAGE<<endl;

        for(int i=0;i<=(int)strlen(MESSAGE);i++){
                    MESSAGE[i]='\0';
                }
        Successful= send(Sock,"a2 SELECT INBOX\r\n",(int)strlen("a2 SELECT INBOX\r\n")+1,NULL);

        DataEnd=0;
        do{
        long Successful=recv(Sock,MESSAGE1,sizeof(MESSAGE1)/sizeof(char),NULL);        //the listen if he got all
        strcat_s(MESSAGE,MESSAGE1);
        for(int i=0;i<1024;i++){
            if(MESSAGE[i]=='\0'){
                DataEnd=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        }while(DataEnd==0);
        cout<<MESSAGE<<endl;

        for(int i=0;i<=(int)strlen(MESSAGE);i++){
                    MESSAGE[i]='\0';
                }

        system("PAUSE");
    }
    cout<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}`

but what i get in output is

connecting...
connected

then it blocks here...seems gmail is not replying with the "* OK" message
what am i getting wrong

Comment: To get smth you have to request smth

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. You are connecting to `smtp.gmail.com`, which does not host the IMAP services.  You need `imap.gmail.com`.
2. Port 993 is TLS secured.  You will need to use secure sockets to connect to it.  Connecting with a plain socket will not get you anything as it is waiting for you to do an SSL/TLS negotiation.

Comment: SSL and TLS are two different things.  Gmail's port 993 for IMAP uses SSL, not TLS.  It is important to make that distinction because they have different rules and semantics. With SSL, you have to initiate the secure handshake immediately after connecting, before sending any protocol-related commands. With TLS, you have to connect unsecure and send a protocol-specific command to ask permission to then send the secure handshake.

Comment: You are confusing TLS and STARTTLS. Gmail does indeed use TLS, which is the new name for newer version of SSL.

Comment: thanks you all for you replys.i think i got more to learn on secure sockets